# Тянущиеся блоки

Tags: html, css

Как реализовать два тянущихся блока? То есть, если в одном контента больше, то и второй по высоте подстраивался и наоборот...

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="prev">
<a href=""></a>
</div>

<div class="next">
<a href=""></a>
</div>
</div>

.next a, .prev a {
  display: block;
  height: 90px;
}

.prev {
  float: left;
  width: 380px;
}

.next{
  margin-left: 380px;
}
```

Сейчас есть такой фиксированный вариант, помогите сделать его резиновым :)

Answer (score 1):

[4 способа как сделать блоки одинаковой высоты](http://www.getincss.ru/2009/07/11/4-sposoba-kak-sozdat-bloki-kolonki-odinakovoj-vysoty/)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript + jQuery:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     function setEqualHeight(columns)
     {
     var tallestcolumn = 0;
     columns.each(
     function()
     {
     currentHeight = $(this).height();
     if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn)
     {
     tallestcolumn  = currentHeight;
     }
     }
     );
     columns.height(tallestcolumn);
     }
     setEqualHeight($("элементы, которые нужно сделать одинаковой высоты(пример: #sidebarL, #content, #sidebarR)"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Колонки одинаковой высоты](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/kolonki-ravnoy-visoty.html)